# Bring the Activity to front while in Notification Bar is opened

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I have one service which was running in background.

It will open the activity when a time is elapsed.It is working well.

But If the notification bar was opened,it open the activity but it was behind the Notification Bar.

How to bring the activity infront of notification bar when it opened?

Comment: your question is not clear. Do you want to open the activity when u click on the notification ?

Comment: Sorry,I corrected that. I want to bring the activity infront of notification bar when it was opened.

Comment: notification tray is on top of the activity always. I'm not sure if there is a way. Can you clear the notification tray so that the activity becomes visible?

Comment: do you want to hide the notification tray and show your activity as full screen ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to bring the activity infront of notification bar when it opened?

That is not possible. More importantly, the user has the notification drawer open *for a reason*. Please allow the user to complete their work with the notification drawer, at which point in time they can deal with your activity.